# Network error: Software caused connection abort(SSH)

Tags: ssh, winscp

Firstly i apologize my English. Our Azure Linux(Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS) instance has been running for more than a 2 months now. Suddenly tuesday night without any configuration to server, I get randomly "Software caused connection abort" from my automated powershell-script. Script uses Winscp-client for sftp-connection. I get this error randomly in my Putty-client also. Connections to this server are made from multiple servers that are in different networks. We have tried following things:

1. Checked errors from auth.log and there is nothing special. Increased log level to Debug3
2. Checked that iptables is disabled
3. Modified sshd_config-file:
   -MaxStartups 200
   -MaxSessions 200
   -UseDNS no
4. Modified /etc/sysctl.conf with lines:

   -net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65535
   -net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
   -net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
   -net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 4096
   -net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
   -net.core.somaxconn = 2048
   -net.core.netdev_max_backlog=2000
   -kernel.pid_max = 1000000
   -fs.file-max = 1000000
   -net.ipv4.tcp_sack=0
   -net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 16777216
   -net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 16777216
   -net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 2
   -net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
   -net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 50576   64768   98152
   -net.core.wmem_default = 65536
   -net.core.rmem_default = 65536
   -net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling=1
   -net.ipv4.tcp_mem= 98304 131072 196608
   -net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 0
   -net.ipv4.tcp_rfc1337 = 1
   -net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
   -net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=cubic
   -net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 0
   -net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 0
   -net.ipv4.tcp_orphan_retries = 1
   -net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 25
   -net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans = 8192

How can i begin to resolve this issue? Has somebody has this kind of issue? Can it be somekind of network issue with ISP? I checked server stats and CPU and memory loads are low. Like i said this started tuesday night. Nothing has been changed in server.